# Use hover or onmouseover/onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building custom buttons([sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)) for a new website. The buttons will not trigger a link but a javascript that then submits the form.

My solution is to use div (instead of link) with span within.

The question is if I should use onmouseover/onmouseout or is hover a preferred?

**Pleas note :** My website demands javascript else it wont work at all, so there is no problem to use javascript for the button, the question is which way that is the most correct?

Comment: Could not understand this question fully.

Comment: Why don't you use `<a>`? It's more semantic and a fallback for people withoud JS would be wise..

Comment: I agree with Briedis...and one more argument for using the `<a>` is that IE6 does not support `:hover` for anything else than `<a>`

Comment: link is a link, span is a span and a button is a button. That´s html and it stands for a standard. This is just btw... Try think in this standard and use javascript mainly to EXTEND your website (unless it´s a modern web app)

Comment: I was first building this with regular <a> but the link element needs href to show the correct mousepointer. In this case the button will trigger a javascript that submits the form, this means that its not a link in any way. I could add href=# or set the class to show the correct mouse pointer but is this realy right way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to simple use onmouseover/onmouseout on the div element. It will generate some code but it will be safe to use even in IE6.

This will ofcource demand javascript but that will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with CSS because it would require less code and it would work with Javascript disabled

Comment: I don't fully understand the desired behavior, but I agree with Josh: stick with CSS when possible since you can't always count on Javascript.

Comment: I suppose you mean hover then? but that is not supported by IE6?

Comment: @SnowJim IE6 is not supported by *me*

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about jQuery events, it doesn't matter, it's the same.

If you're talking about HTML onmouseover/onmouseout vs. CSS:hover, go for CSS:hover.
It's far easier to maintain, looks cleaner and decreases the size of your HTML which is a mess most times, anyways.

Comment: Yes that was also my thought BUT IE6 do not suport hover on a div element as far as I know?

Comment: That's why you do not use a `div` for it ;)

Comment: Use the a-tag and give it display:block, that works in IE6 and almost makes it a div behaviour-wise